# Best tool to visualize network with 40,000 nodes and 5 million edges

Tags: networking, visualization

I need a good software tool/app to visualize a network with 40k nodes, and 5 million edges.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What are your requirements? Do you need a single map?

Comment: the tool is going to generate more traffic then the user will,  Just kidding. The nodes are they all internal, as in not vpn'd in?

Comment: What's a node? (a server?)  There are only a handful of companies at this scale....

Comment: to me typically a node is anything that has a network cable!

Comment: He didn't explicitly say computer network. It could as well be a social network where nodes represent persons and the edges represent their relations. Or a network overlay for a GIS where nodes represent cities and the edges represent the streets between them. FakeScientiest should probably clarify this in his question. Graph and network theory is quite a part of computer science. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd look at hp openview. It's not cheap and it can be pretty complex but it's robust enough for your use case and has world class enterprise support.

Comment: That's if this is an actual network. Maybe he's trying to design it? He was pretty sparse on the details.

Comment: Right you are. I didn't even think about the fact that he may want a design tool.

Answer (score 1):

Look at TS Visualization or TS Perspectives from Tom Sawyer Software - depending on what you want to do with the Visualization either can handle this scale easily.

[www.tomsawyer.com](http://www.tomsawyer.com)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tool you might try:

http://xavier.informatics.indiana.edu/lanet-vi/

BTW, this was originally posted on stack overflow, so FakeScientist is probably not talking about servers.  He is more likely talking about networks and nodes in general.  Serverfault is probably not the appropriate place for this question.  StackOverflow or SuperUser is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any hierarchy in the data you are looking to visualize you might want to take a look at Structure101g which lets you build your own backend to visualize any programming language or hierarchical data. If you are familiar with Graphviz there's a blog on the differences [here](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/blog/2008/12/graphviz-on-steroids/).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this presentation](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2010/06/25/a-day-in-the-life-of-a-facebook-engineer/), Facebook uses [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/). Should do the trick for you then.

Comment: Well, that's really for monitoring - it looks like another front-end for RRDTool. Which is great, but the OP asked for visualization, which could mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution:
http://iv.slis.indiana.edu/sw/index.html#ivcfw